# Bind Service Depending on Auth Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to bind service to Laravel service container depending on Auth results.

The problem is a want to provide cookie cart to guests and db cart to logged in users. So there is interface Cart with two different implementations (CookieCart and PersistentCart).

How can I do this to provide dependency injection of the relevant implementation?

Comment: Please show the code you're trying to use now and explain what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know how to write code that work, cause middleware runs after service binding, that's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in middleware where `auth()` and cookies are available:

```
app()->bind('Cart', $someCondition ? 'PersistentCart' : 'CookieCart');
```